# static final String or strings.xml

Tags: android

What are the rules for using strings.xml resource files versus an interface where String constants would be defined.

I'm assuming that the strings.xml resource file would be used to define non-functional strings to be used for display purposes such as text in various languages, date rendering formats, etc.

And Interface String constants would be used to define regular expression patterns, Intent extras variable name passing definitions, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct. The key is that you can translate the strings in strings.xml - anything written in English (or any other language) and will be exposed to the user should be in strings.xml so you can translate it.

Patterns/regexes should be Strings for better performance, unless those regexes are language-specific.

Comment: Patterns and regexes in strings.xml? Please tell me more!

Comment: Whoops. Typo. I meant the opposite :P

Comment: Hehe. Great, now it makes sense.

Comment: I'm trying to determine where that fine line is. I'm tempted to put email regex patterns to match specific domains in the strings.xml file.

Comment: Domain names are language-independent, I'd put them into the code. Then again, if you have lots of them, consider a string array resource - it's easier to edit. More importantly, if you have somebody else editing the list, a resource may also be easier to manage.

Comment: Two questions: **1)** Is there really a performance hit to calling `getString(R.string.*)`? **2)** I've found myself using strings.xml extensively in projects that depend on Android Library Projects. I have the majority of my code in the Android Library Project and I retrieve strings from the strings.xml with `getString()`. A lot of these strings differ depending on the Application Project (the one that depends on the library project) so I override them in the respective strings.xml. If I don't do it this way I don't know how else I would easily override these strings.

Comment: @Turbo 1) of course, the system has to a) call the native function getString(), b) figure out which language you're using, c) look up the string ID to see if there is a string available in that language, d) fall back to the default object if that's not the case, e) create a String object for the result. It's a lot-lot slower than basically just "getting a pointer", to use low-level terminology. That said, remember the key to all optimizations - in real life, if something only happens a few times every so often, it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: So - unless you profile it and find it to be a bottleneck, don't change it.

Comment: @EboMike Sorry, forgot to actually ask my 2nd question (thanks for the first response btw). My question is, is it safe to store important Strings (e.g. an md5 key) in strings.xml. Right now I store it in there and since it changes depending on my Application Project, I override the strings.xml file in each project. I noticed while skimming through the docs for Google's In-App purchases that they suggest (for security reasons) to "Construct strings on the fly instead of defining them as constants." so it makes me worry about keeping important strings in the xml file.

Comment: @Turbo - this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407340/how-to-save-private-string-values-in-android-apk In any case, your strings will be easily accessible to anyone, be it in the strings.xml (very easy, it's all in one spot) or as a static string (also pretty easy). That's why they recommend some sort of simple encryption. It can still be bypassed, it'll just take whoever is cracking your app a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

yes, multilanguage constant in string.xml and I like to put other constants in a final class
like this one:

```
    public final class Consts {
    public static final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
    }
```

and calling them this way:

```
    Consts.URL;
```

Answer (score -2):

`String str = getString(R.string.my_string_name);` will do the trick.
It is very convenient to store all Strings in one place (or separate XML files based on your own needs).