# How to save private string values in android apk?

Tags: android

I know i can save strings in res/values/strings.xml but if someone disassembles the dex file or the apk file then he will be able to see HARDCODED strings or res/values/strings.xml strings.

Is there a way to store strings that wont be read if disassembled?

Comment: Maybe you  encrypt those strings somehow?

Comment: yeah, the problem is that if i encrypt them then i need a key which would be hardcoded too, so anyone with this second key would decrypt and obtain the first key, so its the same story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly - no.

---

If you can decrypt/extract any string from your apk, potentially anyone with enough knowledge may look through your code and re-cosntruct the algorithm you use to extract those strings. And then extract them by herself.

Of course you may use some tricks to make it harder. What tricks can be used is actually up to you, Android doesn't provide any by default (AFAIK).

Comment: yeah i guess you are right, but I was hoping for some fantastic miracle that doesnt exist. maybe i wont use tricks at all.

Comment: @inazaruk Would using ProGuard to obfuscate/shrink the app/.apk help? I'm guessing it won't affect hardcoded strings in strings.xml, but will it help to protect String objects (whether they're static, final, or not) in code?

Comment: Proguard would obfuscate the string names, but wouldn't change the contents of the string, so would still be easy to extract. Dexguard offers string obfuscation, but is not free.

Answer (score -2):

If you do not want the data to persist over application sessions, you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: SharedPreferences are not encrypted at all, they are in plain xml file